# hide multiple tr, div with javascript without jquery

Tags: javascript

How can I hide multiple tables based on a result from a checkbox.

```
<input type="checkbox" name="t_show" value="1"  checked="checked" onchange="visible_checkbox(this.id, 't_settings'); update_preview();" id="t_show">
```

Clicking on this div should mean that all the occurring elements with the id t_settings should be hidden.

javascript:

```
 function visible_checkbox(x, y) {
        var v = document.getElementById(x).checked;
        if(v == 1) {
            show(y);
        } else {
            hide(y);
        }
    }
```

Thanks guys.

Comment: You really shouldn't have multiple elements with the same id attribute. Javascript and Html standards don't like that.

Comment: how can i perform such a query to replace multiple tr, lets say with a same class.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> How can I hide multiple tables based on a result from a checkbox.

Do you realize that id is SINGULAR and you can not have more than one element with the same id?

Showing or hiding an element is as simple as setting the display to none.

```
function visible_checkbox(checkboxId, tableId) {
    var isChecked = document.getElementById(checkboxId).checked;
    var showHide = isChecked ?"":"none";
    document.getElementById(tableId).style.display = showHide;
}
```

Personally I would not pass the id,I would just pass the object since there would be no extra lookup:

```
onchange="visible_checkbox(this, 't_settings');
```

JS Code

```
function visible_checkbox(checkbox, tableId) {
    var isChecked = checkbox.checked;
    var showHide = isChecked ?"":"none";
    document.getElementById(tableId).style.display = showHide;
}
```

**As the comment asked, how to do it for multiple ids?**

You can split and loop:

```
onchange="visible_checkbox(this, 't1,t2,t3');
```

JS Code

```
function visible_checkbox(checkbox, tableId) {
    var isChecked = checkbox.checked;
    var showHide = isChecked ?"":"none";
    var ids = tableId.split(",");
    for(var i=0;i<ids.length;i++){
        document.getElementById(ids[i]).style.display = showHide;
    }
}
```

OR you can make it with multiple arguments.

You can loop the arguments:

```
onchange="visible_checkbox(this, 't1', 't2', 't3');
```

JS Code

```
function visible_checkbox(checkbox) {
    var isChecked = checkbox.checked;
    var showHide = isChecked ?"":"none";
    for(var i=1;i<arguments.length;i++){
        document.getElementById(arguments[i]).style.display = showHide;
    }
}
```

Comment: how can i do this with a class="t_settings";

Comment: could you please suggest how would maybe passing multiple ids would work like this-> visible_checkbox(this, "id1,id2,id3"); Thanks

Comment: Edited my post to answer your question on how to do it with multiple ids.

Answer (score 1):

EDIT: I just remembered there is a big compatibility issue with document.getElementsByName() . 
http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/w3c_core.html

Showing another alternative which uses .getElementsByTagName(). I'm still based on the method posted by **epascarello**:

You can iterate through all the DIVs and search for a common id pattern (e.g., using `id="xxx_1"`, `id="xxx_2"`, etc:

```
function visible_checkbox(checkbox, baseId) {
    var isChecked = checkbox.checked;
    var showHide = isChecked ?"":"none";
    var rows = rows.getElementsByTagName("tr");
    for (var i = 0; i < rows.length; ++i) {
        var id = rows[i].id.split("_")[0];
        if (id === baseId) 
            rows[i].style.display = showHide;  
    }
}
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/document.getElementsByTagName

---

This is the first response (disregard)

Use 'name' instead of 'id' and then the method posted by epascarello:

```
function visible_checkbox(checkbox, tableNames) {
    var isChecked = checkbox.checked;
    var showHide = isChecked ?"":"none";
    var elements = document.getElementsByName(tableNames);
    for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; ++i) {
      elements[i].style.display = showHide;  
    }
}
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/document.getElementsByName